# Can I start a sentence with about?

Tags: sentence-starts

Can I start a sentence with 'about'? I am sending a mail to my professor and I was wondering How I should start the mail.

Comment: Could you give us an example sentence, please? Why would you like to use the word *about*?

Answer (score 1):

You can start a sentence with *about*, but you have to put your phrase first, and this can sometimes give the sentence a combative tone.  This may or may not be what you want. For example:

- *About* the house, and for some distance outside the enclosing fence, tall dandelions dotted the otherwise pristine lawn.
- Shakespeare’s plays have greatly influenced my thinking.  *About* his sonnets, I have no opinion.

In the second example, *about* is used to introduce a contrast. Since this is a common usage, starting a sentence with *about* can give the reader the impression that your opinion differs from what has gone before. If you don’t have some kind of preamble, the reader may assume that the contrast is with *them*.